# Flask + React can't parse correct JSON "unexpected character at line 1 column 1"

Tags: reactjs, json, flask, react-hooks

I'm running simple Flask back end

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return {"name": "John", "age": 30}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and trying to log JSON on front end

```
function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([{}])

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost:5000/").then(
            res => res.json()
        ).then(
            data => {
                setData(data)
                console.log(data)
            }
        )
    }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also in `package.json` I have `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000/",`

No matter what I always get

> JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

What's causing the issue and how can I fix this?

UPD:

After adding CORS and `http://localhost:5000` to `fetch` and `package.json` I started to receive another error of

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null) Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.`

UPD2:

The previous error was caused by having `https` instead of `http` in

```
 useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/")
```

Comment: Is `res.json()` where the problem occurs?  If so, what does `res.text()` produce?  In the browser's debugging tools, what is the exact response body from the server?

Comment: Are the answers correct then?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are running your flask app in a different port, like, for example, if your backend is exposed on `http://localhost:8000/` and you React app is running at `http://localhost:3000/`, then you need to specify the host in your `fetch` request, like

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/").then( // Or whatever is your backend host/port
        res => res.json()
    ).then(
        data => {
            setData(data);
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        }
    )
}, [])
```

I also suggest you to add `return data;` as a best practice, so you can chain multiple `.then()`.

It is likely that your are getting the error since the answer you are receiving, from the frontend (`localhost:3000/`, the one you are using by mistake) is somethin like a not found page that begins with `<html>` tag, that's why you are getting the `unexpected character` error, since the not found page does not contains JSON, but HTML instead.

Answer (score 0):

your fetch url is just "/"? because if you are trying to acces a server localhost, need to set "http://localhost:YourPORT/". Try it to your fetch.
Don't forget to configure the CORS in your server for access locally.

Answer (score 0):

change your front to :

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({}); // empty object

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/").then(
      res => res.json()
    ).then(
      data => {
        setData(data);
        console.log(data);
      }
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* Display the data */}
      <p>Name: {data.name}</p>
      <p>Age: {data.age}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and check your problem